# How to decode quoted-printable file using command line on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line

I know it can be done using JavaScript or PHP, but is there a command line utility for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A perl one-liner:

```bsh
echo "$input" | perl -MMIME::QuotedPrint -0777 -nle 'print decode_qp($_)'
```

MIME::QuotedPrint is a core perl module, so that should work without any additional installation.

Comment: Do you know about a Python equivalent?

Comment: No I don't. But a quick look at the python docs reveals https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html

Comment: `cat qp.html | perl -MMIME::QuotedPrint -0777 -nle 'print decode_qp($_)' > html.html` converts a file qp.html with quoted-printable encoded HTML to a valid HTML file html.html.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3.x:   (Tested on Cygwin)

```
python -c 'import sys,quopri;quopri.decode(sys.stdin,sys.stdout.buffer)' < infile > outfile
```

Comment: this seems to work also with `Python 2.6.6` on RedHat 6.3. I use with `python -c 'import quopri ; print(quopri.encodestring("'"${QUOI}"'",header=1)) '` (and output redirection in a file)

Comment: I had to write: python3 -c ...

Answer (score 3):

This is what I was looking for (strange example found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)).

```
$ brew install qprint
$ echo "J'interdis aux marchands de vanter trop leurs marchandises. Car ils se font =
vite p=C3=A9dagogues et t'enseignent comme but ce qui n'est par essence qu'=
un moyen, et te trompant ainsi sur la route =C3=A0 suivre les voil=C3=A0 bi=
ent=C3=B4t qui te d=C3=A9gradent, car si leur musique est vulgaire ils te f=
abriquent pour te la vendre une =C3=A2me vulgaire." | qprint -d
J'interdis aux marchands de vanter trop leurs marchandises. Car ils se font vite pédagogues et t'enseignent comme but ce qui n'est par essence qu'un moyen, et te trompant ainsi sur la route à suivre les voilà bientôt qui te dégradent, car si leur musique est vulgaire ils te fabriquent pour te la vendre une âme vulgaire.
```

Comment: This also works on Ubuntu versions 16 and 20. sudo apt install qprint

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a simple command line utility for this. This has the advantage, that you do not need any fullgrown 3rd party programming language, with all the implications that has.

It's called `tcucodec`. I don't know about MAC, but for debian users, you can install it with:

```bash
apt install tokyocabinet-bin
```

It has a variety of de- and encoders. See the man page for more details. For your specific concern, to encode use:

```bash
echo "Some German umlauts: äöüÄÖÜ and the ß" | tcucodec quote
```

Which yields the output:

```
Some German umlauts: =C3=A4=C3=B6=C3=BC=C3=84=C3=96=C3=9C and the =C3=9F
```

To decode, add a `-d` switch after `quote`:

```bash
echo "Some German umlauts: =C3=A4=C3=B6=C3=BC=C3=84=C3=96=C3=9C and the =C3=9F" | tcucodec quote -d
```

Which gives you back the original text:

```
Some German umlauts: äöüÄÖÜ and the ß
```

The text is converted bytewise from its charset. As you can see the umlauts are 2-byte utf8 character and therefore result in two encoded characters.